# Bluetooth Headset's microphone recognized as keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, headset

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. I'm connecting my bluetooth headset, which works perfectly on the old laptop with 18.04, and it seems to be recognized as a keyboard. I also tried with my colleagues' headsets, always bluetooth, but the problem persists.

The audio is fine, but the microphone is not working.

This is the log:

```
Aug  3 10:05:46 mob-agabellini bluetoothd[773]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_6A_8E_16_D1_34/sep1/fd1: fd(38) ready
Aug  3 10:05:46 mob-agabellini rtkit-daemon[1062]: Supervising 14 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Aug  3 10:05:46 mob-agabellini rtkit-daemon[1062]: Successfully made thread 6108 of process 1743 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Aug  3 10:05:46 mob-agabellini rtkit-daemon[1062]: Supervising 15 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini kernel: [  746.539326] input: BH-M9 (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input25
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device BH-M9 (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event19)
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (**) BH-M9 (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'BH-M9 (AVRCP)'
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1025]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device BH-M9 (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event19)
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1025]: (**) BH-M9 (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1025]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'BH-M9 (AVRCP)'
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event19 13:83 fd 94 paused 0
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (**) BH-M9 (AVRCP): always reports core events
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event19"
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) event19 - BH-M9 (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) event19 - BH-M9 (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) event19 - BH-M9 (AVRCP): device removed
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input25/event19"
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "BH-M9 (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 21)
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "it"
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1025]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event19 13:83 fd 30 paused 1
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1025]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:83
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) event19 - BH-M9 (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1837]: (II) event19 - BH-M9 (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug  3 10:05:47 mob-agabellini gnome-shell[2048]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
```

Is there anything I can do? Is it a possible bug?

Thank you,
Andrew